# CryptoJS decrypted value differ from the original value

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt some strings and decrypt it with the use of `CryptoJS` (AES-256).

My javascript code:

```
function hexStringToByte(str) {
    if (!str) {
        return new Uint8Array();
    }
    
    var a = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i+=2) {
        a.push(parseInt(str.substr(i,2),16));
    }
    
    return new Uint8Array(a);
}

function aesEcryption(input, key, type){
    var xx = input;
    console.log("Print Value");
    console.log(xx);
    console.log(key);
    var key  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);
    var iv   = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('00000000000000000000000000000000');
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(xx, key, {iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding});
    console.log("Encrypted");
    console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext))
    console.log(encrypted.toString());
    return encrypted.toString();
}


function aesDecryption(encryptedString, key, type){
    console.log("testttt");
    console.log(key);
    console.log(encryptedString);
    var key  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);
    var iv   = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('00000000000000000000000000000000');
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedString, key,{iv:iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding});
    decrypted = decrypted.toString();
    console.log("decrpyted");
    // console.log(typeof decrypted);
    // console.log(decrypted);
    return decrypted;
}
```

My setup:
`fefe3124bdc21e8a1c1b3fdfb84c79950b394b8f86fd49dddb616037b1bc2474` (key)

`a` (Input)

`Qw==` (Encrypted string)

`d5` (decrypted value)

May I know which part of my code logic is wrong ?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the expected value was supposed to be.

Comment: For plaintexts whose length is not an integer multiple of the block size (16 bytes for AES), and with padding disabled, CryptoJS silently pads the plaintext with 0x00 values until the length criterion is met. Then the encryption is performed and the ciphertext is truncated to the original plaintext length. The same happens during decryption (padding with 0x00 values, decrypting, truncating to the original ciphertext length). This processing is actually a design flaw/bug, as evidenced by the incorrect decryption. CryptoJS should generate an error message instead (like other libraries).

Comment: @ArtjomB.erm, the expected value of course need to be equal with the input value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have figured out why the value would be different. Just need to remove the padding option, the decrypted value will be same as the original.

`var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(xx, key, {iv: iv});`

`var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedString, key,{iv:iv});`

I am just adding this answer, incase someone had the same issue as me.

Cheers!